# Metal fragment shader receives incorrect interpolated vertex z values

Tags: objective-c, apple-m1, metal

I have a simple vertex shader that outputs position and color and a fragment shader that outputs color. There is also depth testing enabled with a texture that I created.

```
struct VertexOut {
  float4 v_vertex [[position]];
  float4 v_color;
  float4 vsVertex;
};

vertex VertexOut vertexShader(uint vertexID [[ vertex_id ]],
                             const device RigidFormatPos* vertices [[ buffer(0) ]],
                             const device StdVertexData* vertexData [[ buffer(1) ]],
                             constant SettingsUBO& sceneUniforms [[ buffer(2) ]],
                             constant MeshUBO& perMesh [[ buffer(3) ]]) {
         VertexOut out;

        out.v_vertex = sceneUniforms.cameras[0].projectFromWorld * perMesh.worldFromModel * float4(vertices[vertexID].pos.xyz, 1.0);
        out.v_color = float4(float3(vertexData[vertexID].color.rgb, 1.f));
        out.vsVertex = out.v_vertex;
        return out;
}

fragment half4 fragmentShader(VertexOut in [[stage_in]]) {
 return half4(half3(in.v_color.rgb), 1.f);
}
```

The screen dimensions are 800x600.

Xcode debugger shows the value of `in.v_vertex.z = ~857.3434` while it has to be in the range [0,1] after the divide by w. The value of in.vsVertex which is in clip space that I have manually cached and output from the vertex shader shows correct z value that after divide by w would be in the range [0,1].
This causes depth test to fail.

Has anyone encountered anything like this. Any ideas on where to look next?

If I manually output depth values to the depth buffer using `depth = in.vsVertex.z / in.vsVertex.w` depth test works as expected.

I am rendering to a CAMetalDrawable render target color attachement, using a depth texture that I created.

Comment: Can you share the layout of RigidFormatPos, SettingsUBO & StdVertexData? Are you using packed or nit packed vectors there? Also how do you feed data in respective buffer? Are you using vannila apole libs or simd etc or are you using c/c++ libs like glm to manage data while on CPU?

Comment: Also how you are setting up camera Matrix?